# How to increase heap size for particular WAR on WAS?

Tags: websphere, java

I have a WAS where a particular WAR file is deployed. This WAR file runs okay most of the time, however at times it would run to Java OOM issue.

I'd like to know if there is any control to increase the Java HEAP size for that particular WAR?

When I run a ps -eo command I could see the associated process info:

```
/IBM/JRE/bin/java -Xmx768M -Xms768M -Xgcpolicy:gencon .....
```

I am sure the Heap size is set to 768 MB for this WAR, but I received it from the client, and I should not change its content... Or should I adjust one of its XML configuration files inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heap size is a configuration parameter of the whole JVM. It is not applicable to deployment unit such as WAR.

Comment: makes sense, I will look for other approaches on WAS configuration itself, thanks for your clarification!

Comment: There are no other approaches to increase the heap for an individual WAR. But you can easily set the maximum heap for the whole Application Server JVM from the admin console.